# How can I have multiple mysql aggregate columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table structure below
[image]

I want to be able to select the following groups

- farmers who grow between 1 and 3 commodities
- farmers who grow between 4 and 6 commodities
- farmers who grow more than 6 commodities

My resultant query should look like below

[image]

I am completely lost as to how to go about this query. I tried

```
SELECT count(*) AS total,

(SELECT count(farmer_id) from farmer_commodities HAVING count(commodity_id) < 3) AS grow1_3,

(SELECT count(farmer_id) from farmer_commodities HAVING count(commodity_id) BETWEEN 4 AND 6) AS grow4_6,

(SELECT count(farmer_id) from farmer_commodities HAVING count(commodity_id) > 6) as grow_above_6

from farmer_commodities
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I initially uploaded the question with a markdown table. The formatting was okay in the preview but didn't come out right when I posted the question

Comment: You should provide it in DDL and DML, so that it can be copied, pasted and executed to create the tables and insert the data. Images are useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
With data as (
SELECT farmer_id,
count(commodity_id) cnt
From table group by 
farmer_id)
Select 
count(*),
Count(distinct case when cnt
    < 3 then farmer_id end),
Count(distinct case when cnt
    BETWEEN 4 AND 6 then farmer_id end),
Count(distinct case when cnt> 6 then farmer_id end) from 
Data;
```

Comment: your query worked but can you please throw more light on ```With data``` and ```from Data```?

Comment: Yeah its basically used to store repeatable used query and avoiding requerying of same data again. Here the usecase was the query would have become complex if i hadnt stored it in some alias. Data is an alias given to reference the complex query for reuse in the original select query making it reference the intermediate results once from the table and avoiding requerying

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this:

```
select grow1_3_commodities, grow4_6_commodities, grow_above_6_commodities from (
     (select farmer_id, count(commodity_id) as grow1_3_commodities from farmer_commodities group by farmer_id HAVING count(commodity_id) < 3) AS grow1_3
join (select farmer_id, count(commodity_id) as grow4_6_commodities from farmer_commodities group by farmer_id HAVING count(commodity_id) BETWEEN 4 AND 6) AS grow4_6
join (SELECT farmer_id, count(farmer_id) as grow_above_6_commodities from farmer_commodities group by farmer_id HAVING count(commodity_id) > 6) as grow_above_6)
where grow1_3.farmer_id = grow4_6.farmer_id and grow4_6.farmer_id = grow_above_6.farmer_id);
```